# SwiftUI: Properly Displaying List within ForEach

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I was playing around with a List in SwiftUI and noticed that it wasn't appearing when I put it in a ForEach loop (it's worth noting that this ForEach loop is in a DisclosureGroup), yet, when I added a `.frame(width: x, height: y)` modifier, the list finally appeared.

[image]

As you can see, this list has static dimensions that don't really look good. What is the proper way to get a List to appear when it is in a ForEach loop (which I think means the List's parent has dynamic size)?

Here's the code I'm looking at:

```
DisclosureGroup {
    ...
    ForEach(someArr) { item in
        Text("Day \(item.number")
        
        let intArr = [1, 2, 3]
        List(intArr, id: \.self) { _ in
            Text("hi")
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any guidance as to how I can properly size this list?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is also the weird spacing around the list, which I'm wondering how to get rid of

Answer (score 0):

do it the other way round: make List the outermost element.

```
List {
    DisclosureGroup {
    ...
        ForEach(someArr) { item in
            Text("Day \(item.number")
    
            let intArr = [1, 2, 3]
            ForEach(intArr, id: \.self) { _ in
                Text("hi")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified, I would like a number of lists to be part of one disclosure group, i.e when I tap the dropdown button, several lists appear, and when I tap it again, they all collapse.

Comment: and you definitely need Lists, right? Custom VStack wouldn't do it?

Comment: I know this is a hack:
  .frame(height: CGFloat(intArr.count) * 50)
 .listStyle(.plain)

... with the listStyle you can get rid of the spacing around the list